# At what concentration do dispersed particles begin behaving like a fluid?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, flow, nanoscience

Suppose that I have a nearly insoluble metallic compound in a solution, and that what little of this compound *does* dissolve aggregates to form nanoparticles. The number of nanoparticles is proportional to the maximum concentration of the compound in solution (its solubility).

The nanoparticles are scattered randomly when the solution is disturbed, and slowly redistribute themeselves towards centers of nucleation (if present) or approximately homogenous distribution.

If I want to model the motion of these nanoparticles within a drop of solution I can either treat them as discrete particles moving through a fluid or as points in a continuous medium, in which case their motion may be better described by fluid dynamics.

My question is this: at approximately what concentration/density does it become appropriate to treat the nanoparticles as a fluid rather than as individual objects suspended in a fluid?

Comment: What sort of information are you trying to obtain with this modelling? At low consentrations hydrodynamic models should emerge by considering the expectation values of probabilistic models (e.g. [the Fokker-Planck equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fokker%E2%80%93Planck_equation)). These probabilistic models are still a form of contiuum model and can happily consider a single particle, if the sort of information they provide is suitable for your purpose.

Comment: I'm hoping to obtain the approximate 'flow' velocity at a given point provided the initial position of the majority of particles. I've never used statistical mechanics, and I honestly hadn't thought about it. Do you think a probabilistic approach would work better than a classical one?